# Abrir janela modal de acordo com o id do Cliente

Tags: php, codeigniter, bootstrap-3

Na view faço um foreach para exibir os clientes, conforme abaixo:

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12">
            <div class="table-responsive">
                <table class="table table-striped">
                    <thead>      
                    <th>Nome</th>                                                                    
                    <th>Profissão</th>
                    <th>CPF</th>                                                                    
                    <th>Tel. Celular</th>
                    <th>E-mail</th>                                            
                    <th>Status</th>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>                           
                        <?php foreach ($cliente as $cli) : ?>
                            <tr>                                                                
                                <td><?= $cli->nomecliente; ?></td>                                                                                                     
                                <td><?= $cli->profissao; ?></td>                                    
                                <td><?= $cli->cpf; ?></td>                                                                                            
                                <td><?= $cli->telcelular; ?></td> 
                                <td><?= $cli->email; ?></td>    
                                <td><?= $cli->status; ?></td>                            
                                <td>                                        
                                    <button type="button" title="Detalhes" href="<?= $cli->codcliente ?>" class="btn btn-info hidden-print" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".clientepf-modal-lg">
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open" aria-hidden="true"></span></button></td>                            
                            </tr>                        
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>             
        </div>            
    </div>
```

E o clicar no botão detalhes, abre o Modal com as informações completas do cliente:

```
<!-- Modal View Cliente -->
<div class="modal fade clientepf-modal-lg"  tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <!--<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>-->
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel"><?= $cliente[0]->nomecliente; ?></h4>                
                <h4 class="modal-title">                                                          
                    <p><font  size="2" face="helvetica">Status: <strong><?php echo $cliente[0]->status; ?></strong></font></p>                                                                                                        
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">                                    
                <input type="hidden" id="codcliente" name="codcliente" value="<?= $cliente[0]->codcliente; ?>">                                
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-3">                            
                        <p><font  size="2" face="helvetica">Nome: <strong><?php echo $cliente[0]->nomecliente; ?></strong></font></p>                                                                                                                                      
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">                            
                        <p><font  size="2" face="helvetica">Nacionalidade: <strong><?php echo $cliente[0]->nacionalidade; ?></strong></font></p>                                                                                                                                        
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3" >                            
                        <p><font  size="2" face="helvetica">Estado Civil: <strong><?php echo $cliente[0]->estadocivil; ?></strong></font></p>                                                                                                                                                                        
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">                            
                        <p><font  size="2" face="helvetica">Profissão: <strong><?php echo $cliente[0]->profissao; ?></strong></font></p>                            
                    </div>
                </div>          
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <p><font  size="2" face="helvetica">CPF: <strong><?php echo $cliente[0]->cpf; ?></strong></font></p>                                
                    </div>           
                    <div class="col-md-3">                            
                        <p><font  size="2" face="helvetica">RG: <strong><?php echo $cliente[0]->id; ?></strong></font></p>                                
                    </div>                    
                    <div class="col-md-3" >
                        <p><font  size="2" face="helvetica">NIS / PIS / PASEP: <strong><?php echo $cliente[0]->pis; ?></strong></font></p>                            
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">                            
                        <p><font  size="2" face="helvetica">CTPS: <strong><?php echo $cliente[0]->ctps; ?></strong></font></p>
                    </div>
                </div>                  
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <p><font  size="2" face="helvetica">Endereço: <strong><?php echo $cliente[0]->endereco; ?></strong></font></p>                                                                                                                                    
                    </div>                        
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <p><font  size="2" face="helvetica">Número: <strong><?php echo $cliente[0]->numero; ?></strong></font></p>                                                                                                                                                                            
                    </div>                
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <p><font  size="2" face="helvetica">Complemento: <strong><?php echo $cliente[0]->complemento; ?></strong></font></p>                                                                                                                                                                                                
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <p><font  size="2" face="helvetica">Bairro: <strong><?php echo $cliente[0]->bairro; ?></strong></font></p>                                                                                                                                                                                                            
                    </div>
                </div> 
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <p><font  size="2" face="helvetica">Cidade: <strong><?php echo $cliente[0]->cidade; ?></strong></font></p>                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
                    </div>                   
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <p><font  size="2" face="helvetica">Estado: <strong><?php echo $cliente[0]->estado; ?></strong></font></p>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3" >
                        <p><font  size="2" face="helvetica">Cep: <strong><?php echo $cliente[0]->cep; ?></strong></font></p>                                                                                    
                    </div>   
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <p><font  size="2" face="helvetica">Email: <strong><?php echo $cliente[0]->email; ?></strong></font></p>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">                    
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <p><font  size="2" face="helvetica">Tel. Celular: <strong><?php echo $cliente[0]->telcelular; ?></strong></font></p>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
                    </div>                     
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <p><font  size="2" face="helvetica">Tel. Residencial: <strong><?php echo $cliente[0]->telresidencial; ?></strong></font></p>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
                    </div>          
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <p><font  size="2" face="helvetica">Tel. Comercial: <strong><?php echo $cliente[0]->telcomercial; ?></strong></font></p>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
                    </div>      
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <p><font  size="2" face="helvetica">Email Secundário: <strong><?php echo $cliente[0]->emailsecundario; ?></strong></font></p>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
                    </div>   
                </div>                          
                <div class="row">       
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <p><font  size="2" face="helvetica">Site: <strong><?php echo $cliente[0]->site; ?></strong></font></p>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <p><font  size="2" face="helvetica">Rede Social: <strong><?php echo $cliente[0]->redesocial; ?></strong></font></p>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <p><font  size="2" face="helvetica">Data de Nascimento: <strong><?php echo $cliente[0]->dtnascimento; ?></strong></font></p>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
                    </div>  
                </div>
                <div class="row">    
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <p><font  size="2" face="helvetica">Pai: <strong><?php echo $cliente[0]->nomepai; ?></strong></font></p>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <p><font  size="2" face="helvetica">Mãe: <strong><?php echo $cliente[0]->nomemae; ?></strong></font></p>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <p><font  size="2" face="helvetica">Observação: <strong><?php echo $cliente[0]->obs; ?></strong></font></p>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
                    </div> 
                    <div class="col-md-3" >
                        <p><font  size="2" face="helvetica">Dt. Cadastro: <strong><?php echo $cliente[0]->dtcadastro; ?></strong></font></p>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
                    </div>
                </div>                             
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button"  title="Imprimir" class="btn btn-primary  hidden-print" onclick="myFunction()">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-print" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>                                                              
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm hidden-print" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>                                        
                </div>
            </div> <!-- modal-body -->        
        </div> <!-- modal-content -->
    </div> <!-- modal-dialog modal-lg -->
</div> <!-- modal fade clientepf-modal-lg -->
```

Ocorre que o Modal, só está exibindo o primeiro Cliente da lista ao clicar no botão detalhes de qualquer cliente.

Como faço para que o botão de detalhes de cada cliente da lista exiba informações do cliente selecionado? Agradeço desde já!

Comment: Não é por que você está acessando o objeto $cliente[0] ao invés do índice correto ?

Comment: Sim @LucasBrogni mas como eu faço para acertar isso? obrigado

Comment: @Ramiro Pelo que entendi, você quer mostrar informações do cliente que eu cliquei em "Detalhes" no modal, caso seja isso, pode criar um código ajax que vai ser chamado sempre que clicar no button "Detalhes" e esse ajax irá retornar os dados do cliente escolhido e irá escrever no modal.

Comment: @Piupz e como faz isso? rs ...não tenho muita intimidade com ajax

Answer (score 3):

Basicamente, você irá fazer requisição via AJAX ao clicar no `button` de Detalhes.

Na sua view, irá ficar assim:

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12">
            <div class="table-responsive">
                <table class="table table-striped">
                    <thead>      
                    <th>Nome</th>                                                                    
                    <th>Profissão</th>
                    <th>CPF</th>                                                                    
                    <th>Tel. Celular</th>
                    <th>E-mail</th>                                            
                    <th>Status</th>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>                           
                        <?php foreach ($cliente as $cli) : ?>
                            <tr>                                                                
                                <td><?= $cli->nomecliente; ?></td>                                                                                                     
                                <td><?= $cli->profissao; ?></td>                                    
                                <td><?= $cli->cpf; ?></td>                                                                                            
                                <td><?= $cli->telcelular; ?></td> 
                                <td><?= $cli->email; ?></td>    
                                <td><?= $cli->status; ?></td>                            
                                <td>                                        
                                    <button type="button" title="Detalhes" class="btn btn-info hidden-print btn-detalhes" data-codigo="<?= $cli->codcliente ?>" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".clientepf-modal-lg">
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open" aria-hidden="true"></span></button></td>                            
                            </tr>                        
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>             
        </div>            
    </div>

    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
       <div class="modal-dialog newWidth">
          <div class="modal-content">
             <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Detalhes do Cliente</h4>
             </div>
             <div class="modal-body"></div>
             <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
             </div>
          </div>
       </div>
    </div>
```

Repare que no button, adicionei uma nova classe chamada `btn-detalhes` e um novo atributo com o código do cliente chamado `data-codigo`

No mesmo arquivo da view, você coloca esse bloco no final:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$( ".btn-detalhes" ).click(function() {

    var id = $(this).data('codigo');
    $.get('http://localhost/getClientes.php?cliente='+id, function(html){
        $('#myModal .modal-body').html(html);
        $('#myModal').modal('show', {backdrop: 'static'});
    });

}); 

</script>
```

Nesse bloco acima, irá ser executado toda vez que o `btn-detalhes` tiver o evento de `click`, onde irá chamar uma página no seu site, no meu caso estou chamando de `getClientes.php` que retornará o HTML a ser exibido no modal.

Na página que você configurou no bloco acima, irá ter que fazer a consulta SQL e fazer o HTML para retornar pelo Jquery. Somente o HTML irá ficar mais ou menos assim: (Não esqueça de fazer a consulta SQL com o id que irá pegar via `$_GET['id']` antes de montar o HTML, aqui só estou montando o HTML)

Arquivo chamado getClientes.php:

```
       <input type="hidden" id="codcliente" name="codcliente" value="<?= $cliente->codcliente; ?>">                                
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">                            
                <p><font  size="2" face="helvetica">Nome: <strong><?php echo $cliente->nomecliente; ?></strong></font></p>                                                                                                                                      
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">                            
                <p><font  size="2" face="helvetica">Nacionalidade: <strong><?php echo $cliente->nacionalidade; ?></strong></font></p>                                                                                                                                        
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3" >                            
                <p><font  size="2" face="helvetica">Estado Civil: <strong><?php echo $cliente->estadocivil; ?></strong></font></p>                                                                                                                                                                        
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">                            
                <p><font  size="2" face="helvetica">Profissão: <strong><?php echo $cliente->profissao; ?></strong></font></p>                            
            </div>
        </div>          
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <p><font  size="2" face="helvetica">CPF: <strong><?php echo $cliente->cpf; ?></strong></font></p>                                
            </div>           
            <div class="col-md-3">                            
                <p><font  size="2" face="helvetica">RG: <strong><?php echo $cliente->id; ?></strong></font></p>                                
            </div>                    
            <div class="col-md-3" >
                <p><font  size="2" face="helvetica">NIS / PIS / PASEP: <strong><?php echo $cliente->pis; ?></strong></font></p>                            
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">                            
                <p><font  size="2" face="helvetica">CTPS: <strong><?php echo $cliente->ctps; ?></strong></font></p>
            </div>
        </div>                  
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <p><font  size="2" face="helvetica">Endereço: <strong><?php echo $cliente->endereco; ?></strong></font></p>                                                                                                                                    
            </div>                        
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <p><font  size="2" face="helvetica">Número: <strong><?php echo $cliente->numero; ?></strong></font></p>                                                                                                                                                                            
            </div>                
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <p><font  size="2" face="helvetica">Complemento: <strong><?php echo $cliente->complemento; ?></strong></font></p>                                                                                                                                                                                                
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <p><font  size="2" face="helvetica">Bairro: <strong><?php echo $cliente->bairro; ?></strong></font></p>                                                                                                                                                                                                            
            </div>
        </div> 
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <p><font  size="2" face="helvetica">Cidade: <strong><?php echo $cliente->cidade; ?></strong></font></p>                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
            </div>                   
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <p><font  size="2" face="helvetica">Estado: <strong><?php echo $cliente->estado; ?></strong></font></p>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3" >
                <p><font  size="2" face="helvetica">Cep: <strong><?php echo $cliente->cep; ?></strong></font></p>                                                                                    
            </div>   
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <p><font  size="2" face="helvetica">Email: <strong><?php echo $cliente->email; ?></strong></font></p>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">                    
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <p><font  size="2" face="helvetica">Tel. Celular: <strong><?php echo $cliente->telcelular; ?></strong></font></p>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
            </div>                     
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <p><font  size="2" face="helvetica">Tel. Residencial: <strong><?php echo $cliente->telresidencial; ?></strong></font></p>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
            </div>          
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <p><font  size="2" face="helvetica">Tel. Comercial: <strong><?php echo $cliente->telcomercial; ?></strong></font></p>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
            </div>      
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <p><font  size="2" face="helvetica">Email Secundário: <strong><?php echo $cliente->emailsecundario; ?></strong></font></p>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
            </div>   
        </div>                          
        <div class="row">       
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <p><font  size="2" face="helvetica">Site: <strong><?php echo $cliente->site; ?></strong></font></p>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <p><font  size="2" face="helvetica">Rede Social: <strong><?php echo $cliente->redesocial; ?></strong></font></p>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <p><font  size="2" face="helvetica">Data de Nascimento: <strong><?php echo $cliente->dtnascimento; ?></strong></font></p>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
            </div>  
        </div>
        <div class="row">    
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <p><font  size="2" face="helvetica">Pai: <strong><?php echo $cliente->nomepai; ?></strong></font></p>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <p><font  size="2" face="helvetica">Mãe: <strong><?php echo $cliente->nomemae; ?></strong></font></p>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <p><font  size="2" face="helvetica">Observação: <strong><?php echo $cliente->obs; ?></strong></font></p>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
            </div> 
            <div class="col-md-3" >
                <p><font  size="2" face="helvetica">Dt. Cadastro: <strong><?php echo $cliente->dtcadastro; ?></strong></font></p>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
            </div>
```

Espero que isso dê para entender mais ou menos como funcionará o processo de consulta, recomendo a leitura desse [guia](https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/pt/tutorials/a-beginners-guide-to-ajax-with-jquery--cms-25126), que ensina legal o conceito de AJAX.

Comment: não consegui desse forma. Talvez eu não tenha sido claro na pergunta.